# Two json responses to be added in wso2 ESB

Tags: json, wso2, esb

I have two json responses in my Requestpayloadsequence files in WSO2 ESB.

First json response (response1) :

```
{

    "first" : true,
    "second" : {

    },
    "third" : [{

    }]
    }
```

2nd JSON response (response2) :

```
[
{
    "item1": "123456",

    "item2": "5678"

},

{
    "item1": "8976",
    "item2": "abcd"

}
```

I want to concatenate these 2 json responses. I am using "fn:concat" function to concatenante these two responses but the final response coming is not a valid json. I am using the below property :

```
<property name="final" expression="fn:concat(get-property('response1'),get-property('response2'))"/>
```

Could any body help me to know how can  i concatenate both these two JSON responses together to have a valid json response. Please advice

The final json is coming as :

```
    {

    "first" : true,
    "second" : {

    },
    "third" : [{

    }]
}
[
{
    "item1": "123456",

    "item2": "5678"

},

{
    "item1": "8976",
    "item2": "abcd"

}
```

Comment: can you share an example of the final json you expected?

Comment: @JorgeInfanteOsorio  Actually i have to use xpath expression to retrieve values like "first", "item1", "item2" etc (ex: //first or // item1). but the problem is concatenation of both these json responses using "fn:concat" is not a valid json. so i am not able to retrieve the xpath values. the final json respinse is shown above and this is not a proper json.

Comment: I ask by the correct json you need to have. maybe you can use the JS mediator and use the concat method in  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: your second json response it not valid. so how the concatenated one is valid?

Comment: @lakshman     sorry i missed the "]" bracket at the last line. It is a valid json.

Comment: @JorgeInfanteOsorio I have to use the same in WSO2 esb. IMO, the link you referred won't work for wso2 code.

Comment: Does anybody has answer for this ? Please advice